# Is An Initial Query Required For An Entity Update With A Child Object

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an Album entity:

```
public class Album
{
    public Album() { }

    [Key]
    [Column("AlbumId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }        
    public int ReleaseYear { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }        
    public int ComposerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ComposerId")]
    public Composer Composer { get; set; }


}
```

Which contains Composer as a child object:

```
public class Composer
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ComposerId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In my update method for Album, I have the following code which works correctly:

```
public void UpdateAlbum(Album album)
{
    using (var context = new MusicCatelogContext())
    {
        try
        {
                Album albumEntity = context.Albums
                        .Where(a => a.Id.Equals(album.Id))
                        .Include(a => a.Composer)
                        .First();                        

                Composer composerEntity = context.Composers
                        .Where(c => c.Id.Equals(album.Composer.Id))
                        .First();

                context.Entry(albumEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(album);
                albumEntity.Composer = composerEntity;


                context.SaveChanges();

        }
```

The above code, although working, required two queries to the database. I would have expected to be able to just attach the updated Album entity as below:

```
public void UpdateAlbum(Album album)
{
    using (var context = new MusicCatelogContext())
    {
        try
        {    
            context.Entry(album).State = EntityState.Modified;                
            context.SaveChanges();    
        }
```

However, when I try this code, the follow exception is raised when I try to set the state:

`A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'Composer.Id' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of 'Album.ComposerId' on the other end.`

I've done a lot of research and I'm still unsure why this is the case. I should note that the entire Composer object passed to `UpdateAlbum` in the `album` parameter is the new updated version.

Therefore, my questions are:

1. Is the first version the only way to update an existing entity with a child object (i.e. an initial SELECT is required)?
2. If not, what is wrong with the second version of the code that is causing the error?

Thanks.

Comment: To my knowledge, this is standard behaviour of EF. I also believe it is correct behaviour. The time that you hit the DB, many things might have happened, another process/user has removed the object or changed the object. You are developer want to know about this. You should also ask yourself why you worry about this. Only when you have massive bulk updates you are having a performance penalty but not here.

Comment: The error is also standard, because EF wants to insert a new object, it is not in its context.

Comment: context.Entry(album).State = EntityState.Modified; does two things: Attach the object album to the context and tell EF that this object is to be saved to the database as it is. However, the ComposerId does not match the Id of the composer in the object graph relating to album (you've just set it to a different value). Either set the FK previous to saving, do not expose the FK property (let EF handle it), or attach the correct composer entry to the context like you did in the second example.

Comment: @Aldert EF will not insert a new object, since the .Entry<> method works on the ChangeTracker (without navigation properties and therefore without accounting for referenced entries). .Set<T>.Add beforehand on the other hand would indeed try to insert the related entry and likely throw a different error.

Comment: @Devil, to my knowledge this is only the case in teh scope of the context object. Normally you instantiate you context, run your business logic and dispose of the context. You are right, within this context, a ChangeTracker is useful. In the example above the context just got created so the changetracker is empty.

Comment: Actually John writes good code!